# Insert data into SQL Server CE for windows phone

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, insert, sql-server-ce

I want to add some data to an empty database, this is my piece of code

```
private void readSQLCE()
{
    db = new MyDataContext("isostore:/qq.sdf");

    cust newcust = new cust
    {
        C_Id = 1,
        C_Name = "Amop",
        C_Place = "Poik"
    };

    db.CS.InsertOnSubmit(newcust);
}
```

What else is needed to add to this to insert my data into the SQL Server CE database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a

```
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: that is throwing an exception and the rows aren't getting updated :(

Comment: Which exception?  It is usual to have the ID be auto-generated - check whether you should be specifying the C_ID ...

Comment: There was an sqlexception, caught it and then added submitChanges(). Working exceptionally :)